# Persistent data with finer granularity than a session in django

Tags: django, session

Suppose that a staff member using a web site can exchange tickets for a customer.  It is convenient to store data about the multi-view exchange in the session.  But more than one exchange might be going on at the same time.

One way to keep track of the separate data in the session is to create a sub-session key and use that to access the session data.  This key would need to be part of the view as a hidden input or it would need to be in the URL.  This all gets pretty messy and the hidden variable method isn't great since redirects might occur during the exchange.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a database table that tracks information for a particular exchange and read/write from it when opening/submitting your wizard pages.  Sessions are much more volatile by nature.

Comment: How would the ID for the database be stored and resubmitted with the multiple views?  What are wizard pages?

Comment: When you indicated it was a multi-view, I assumed you meant multiple view pages, like a wizard.  (page 1 submits to page 2 submits to page 3, etc)